# Ionic 3 - How to make height of paragraph same as slide height?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to put paragraph with background inside slides. The background can not be fit as slide height. I checked so many ways but same result.

here my code

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide style="align-items: flex-start; height:auto;">
    <p style="white-space:initial; background-color:lightGray" text-justify>
            Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide style="align-items: flex-start; height:auto;">
        <p style="white-space:initial; background-color:lightGray" text-justify>
            Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
        </p>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Here screenshot that explain the problem with wanted solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ion-slide
{
  background-size:cover;
}
```